# Pass ID to resource controller for edit

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to send ID of record to resource controller for edit through AJAX request in Laravel. My code is like below.

```
function editdetails(id) {
              $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:"{{ route('users.edit', id ) }}",
                success:function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                }
              });
            }
```

But I am getting error like below.

```
Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

Comment: Is that JS file or blade template file? If that is a JS file, you can't use blade syntax there.

Comment: Thanks @Tpojka. It is a blade file and I am using JavaScript within it.

Comment: So the error you made is trying to use the JS variable `id` in a PHP function `route(...)`. PHP runs before JS, so by the time `id` is available, the PHP code has already failed to run, since PHP has no idea what `id` is supposed to be. You can use PHP variables in JS, like `var myVariable = {{ $phpVariable }}`, but you cannot use JS variables in PHP. You can use the answer below with a placeholder and replace, or an AJAX request to get the variable, etc. This is one of the main differences between server-side and client-side code; order of execution; server side first, _then_ client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
var id = id;
var url = "{{ route('users.edit',":id") }}";
url = url.replace(':id', id);
```

As in your code:
Replace this:

```
function editdetails(id) {
      var id = id;
      var url = "{{ route('users.edit',":id") }}";
      url = url.replace(':id', id);

              $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url: url,
                success:function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                }
              });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using javascript here, you can't use blade syntax. In order to achieve this, you either have to use URL as a string that you defined in your routes file:

```
url: "/your/url/" + id 
//or
url: `/your/url/${id}`
```

or you can save your route in some hidden element on you page and use it in js, for example:

```
//define in blade file
<input type="hidden" id="edit-url" value="{{route('users.edit', $id )}}">
   
//use in js file
let url = $('#edit-url').val()
url: url
```

Comment: *"Since you are using javascript here, you can't use blade syntax"* - That statement is only correct if this is a `.js` file. But using a `<script>` tag within a `.blade.php` file _does_ allow you to use blade syntax (`{{ }}`, etc.) inside of JS. Other than that erroneous statement, this answer is a decent enough alternative.

Comment: @TimLewis correct, forgot about that. Thanks